# Is there any difference in memory allocation using new opeartor in java wrapper class?

Tags: java, memory-management

Is there any difference in memory allocation using new opeartor in java wrapper class?

For the class,

```
public class TestClass {
    Integer r=9;
}
```

size of memory allocated is 5152 bytes in 32 bit JVM

where as for

```
public class TestClass1 {

    Integer i=new Integer(1);

}
```

size of memory is 32 bytes.

why there is less memory allocation for class TestClass1?

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
Integer r = 9;
```

actually becomes:

```
Integer r = Integer.valueOf(9);
```

due to autoboxing, which retrieves a cached Integer object.  If you check the JLS [Section 5.1.7](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.7) on Boxing Conversions it states that Integer values between -128 an 127 are cached.  In practice, the first call to `Integer.valueOf()` (which includes autoboxing occurrences) will initialize the cache which may account for a different memory footprint.

Comment: In that case, wouldn't it have less memory than TestClass1?

Comment: I have expanded my answer to include initialization of the integer cache which may account for a different size in memory.

Answer (score 1):

How are you measuring this?

It seems to me that the JVM would be well within its rights to optimise away the  Integer in TestClass1, since its never used, leaving a reference to an empty class

Comment: But those members could be referenced externally, since they have default package private access modifier.

Answer (score 1):

`Integer.valueOf` which doesn't always create a new object. Thats why memory allocation is different for

```
Integer r = 9;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Sizer {

  public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
    Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();

    // Pre-instantiate variables
    long memoryBefore = 0;
    long memoryAfter = 0;
    int loops = 10;

    runGC(r, loops);
    memoryBefore = getMemoryUsage(r);

//     Long lo = new Long(1);
    TestClass in = new TestClass(); 

    runGC(r, loops);
    memoryAfter = getMemoryUsage(r);

    System.out.println("Diff in size is " + (memoryAfter - memoryBefore));
  }

  public static void runGC(Runtime r, int loops) throws Exception {
    for(int i=0; i<loops; i++) {
      r.gc();
      Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
  }

  public static long getMemoryUsage(Runtime r) throws Exception {
    long usedMemory = r.totalMemory() - r.freeMemory();
    System.out.println("Memory Usage: " + usedMemory);
    return usedMemory;
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi, on stack you are able to edit your post. You may consider to move this to the question to have more clarity.

Comment: running a full GC more than once doesn't do anything (unless you have multiple threads to allocate in the same time)

Comment: The accuracy of the free memory is typically only in the MB range. i.e. you can allocate many objects and not change the free memory.  I suggest you try creating 10 million of these in an array and see how much difference it makes.

Answer (score 0):

Q: Why there is less memory allocation for class TestClass1?

As already krock mentioned the

```
Integer i = 9;
```

will become

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(9);
```

This instruction cause that the cache has to be initialized before you can used it.

The cache contains values from -128 to usually 127, this give 255 values that has to be initialized (`new Integer(i)`). And this cause such big memory usage.

Resuming instruction

> - `i = new Interger(9);` - Will create one Integer object,
> - `i = 9;` - Will create at least 255 Integer objects and one array.

FYI: The cache initialization does not depend of the boxed value. The cache is also initialized when you are boxing values lower then -128 and greater then usually 127.